# Oulook 2010 displays images in mail signature at 166%

Tags: html, css, outlook, signature

When I try and create an HTML email signature and choosing it as my signature in Outlook the resulting display is horrendous. It literally ignores all the inline styles I specify on my text (eg, font-size:13px) and appears to enlarge things by about 66%. Even when I use the signature editor, my images end up enlarged. All the content lives inside a table layout.

I've tried many fixes from around the web, including opening the HTML in a browser and selecting all, then copying and pasting into the editor window. Even when I insert the image via the editor, it still comes out at that bigger size on the receiver's end. I've tried adding additional headers too.

I'd appreciate any input to help me solve this. The signature works fine in Thunderbird.

Comment: Are you using DPI scaling? I would guess that your display is set at 150% and it's affecting your signature.

Comment: Outlook  rescales the image as if it was a 96dpi image. If you have a picture of 150dpi with a height off 88px, it will be displayed as an image of 56px high. Conversly, If your picture is less than 96dpi, then the opposite happens. A picture of 88px high with a dpi of 32 would then result in a 96dpi image of 264px high. So the result will be a very large image. To work around this, you can re-render the image to 96dpi yourself while maintaining the dimensions of the picture (for instance with IrfanView).

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for the comments. I didnt get any notices about these responses, so apologies for the delay. I have effectively given up on this issue. I've tried 96DPI images but the signature just keeps blowing up. I also have to do everything remotely which isn't helping a bit. I also don't know where to find the DPI scaling you are referring to.